# Is there any way in reading Japanese signs from Microsoft Excel spread sheet cells without automatically filling and trailing phonetic signs?

Tags: components, spreadsheet, gooddata

Is there any way in reading Japanese signs from Microsoft Excel spread sheet cells without automatically filling and trailing phonetic signs? If I intend to read the Japanese sign(s) like '新' from Microsoft Excel spreadsheet by CloudConnect spreadsheet reader component, Microsoft Excel automatically supplies phonetic signs line 'シン' to the original Japanese cell value of '新' internally, and reader reads not as equal to the original value like '新' but add this phonetic signs as a suffix and read it as the value '新シン'. What I would like is to configure reader not to read this phonetic trailing signs but only to read the original cell value on it own, and would like to know how that will be possible.

Comment: Excel (.xls) data reader doesn't read above described unwanted trailing phonetic signs to japanese character cell values automatically filled by microsoft excel to each cells internally. I think this behaviour of Excel (.xls) data reader can be regarded as a natural, rational, reasonable behaviour therefore should be applied as those of spreadsheet reader. But the use of Excel (.xls) data reader for our case is not appropriate since it doesn't accept file decryption password in its menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the read mode option supplied at advanced options of spreadsheet reader component was set at In-memory rather than Stream of default, the reader could read the Japanese character cell values without unnecessary trailing phonetic signs automatically filled by microsoft Excel.